# The Number of Topologies on a Finite Set

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know if there is like a magical formula to know how many topologies exist on a finite set

For example for $X = \{ a, b, c \}$ I found $29$, but I dont know if there are more or how to know this exact number without writing all topologies first.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A000798 and the references therein.

Comment: This link maybe helpful for you: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2313548

Comment: In case you are interested and didn't know your question is equivalent to: how many preorders exists on a finite set. For any topological space $(X,\tau)$ you can define $x\leq y$ if and only $x \in U \Rightarrow y \in U$ giving a preorder $(X,\leq)$. Conversely given a preorder $(X,\leq)$ one can define a topology on $X$ by setting $U \subseteq X$ open if $x \in U \wedge x \leq y \Rightarrow y \in U$ (i.e. $U$ is up closed).  Restricting to finite topological spaces and finite preorders we find that these maps are inverse to each other.

Comment: Another Q is how many inequivalent topologies there are on a finite set. (Equivalent meaning homeomorphic.) I dk whether a formula for this has been found.

Comment: Have a look here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08359.pdf and here: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL9/Benoumhani/benoumhani11.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The number 29 is apparently correct.  See [oeis](http://oeis.org/A000798).  It is the same as the number of quasi orders on the set, as well as some other equivalent formulations.  I don't know any quick way to compute it;  maybe because I can tell a doughnut from a coffee cup. ..

All kidding aside  (or almost all ), consider a set with $5$ labeled elements.   Then there are $2^5$, or $32$ subsets to "work with "...

Now, we need to see how many ways some of these can be selected which meet the definition of a topology...

Namely,  $\emptyset  $ and the whole set, call it $X $;  and closure under finite (which is automatic, here) intersections, and arbitrary unions...

There are, amazing in a way, $6942$ ways to do this...

If you think of how many ways you can choose subsets, you're looking at the power set *again*,  so $2^{2^5} $ ways...
Now, $2^{10}\approx 10^3$, so we're looking at on the order of  $10^9$ collections that we can use to try to build a topology.  ..

Only about  $1$ in every  $10^6$ subsets of the power set qualifies as a topology. ..

The moral of the story seems to be that we have our work cut out for us...  and remember we are only at $n=5$...